# PHP curl POST request with JSON response

Tags: php, json, post, curl, get

I'm trying to send post data and receive an SID from an api(qbittorrent) to send with a get request later. I'm currently stuck with an OK response but the json is NULL. Here's my code:

```
<?php
  $ch = curl_init();
  $fields = array( 'username'=>'Admin','password'=>'mypassword');
  $postvars = '';
  foreach($fields as $key=>$value) {
    $postvars .= $key . "=" . $value . "&";
  }
  $postvars = rtrim($postvars, '&');
  $url = "https://192.123.123.123:8080/login";
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, 1);         
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
  $headers= array('Accept: application/json','application/x-www-form-urlencoded'); 
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$postvars);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT ,3);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
  $response = curl_exec($ch);
  var_dump(json_decode($response, true));
  print "curl response is:" . $response;
  curl_close ($ch);
?>
```

You can see the API documentaiton here https://github.com/qbittorrent/qBittorrent/wiki/WebUI-API-Documentation#authorization

I was able to get the json using powershell as simply as :

```
$prms = @{username="Admin";password="mypassword"}
$res = Invoke-WebRequest https://192.123.123.123:8080/login -Method POST -Body prms -UseBasicParsing
```

but I'm unable to do so with php! If you also feel like heading me right for the get request using the SID as a cookie, i'll be more than welcome :)

Comment: $postvars will have an extra "&" on the end. Is that an issue? ('username=Admin&password=mypassword&'). Also, do you need the loop to concatenate the string or can you just send the array - curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields);

Comment: `$postvars = rtrim($postvars, '&');` is likely needed here to remove the trailing ampersand.

Comment: Edited my question, still getting the same result. The server still replies "ok" and i've tried with a wrong password and I get "Fails"

Comment: @jkns.co I don't really know about what needs to be sent, im assuming a string but i don't think the problem is with the initial request since I get an OK response but more about the data returned :\

Comment: There is likely a problem during the *json_decode*. do `echo json_last_error_msg();` to see what is preventing it to return the JSON object from string. Also `echo $response;` to see what the string is before decoding.

Comment: @trincot $response is "Ok." and json error is "Syntax Error" obviously, I'm not able to get a json response from that, howerver I can with powershell. I'm clueless.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was lying there, changed:

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
```

to

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
```

And I got my json response!

Comment: but you sent the wrong request nonetheless. do both lines.